# Join with positions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have got tables `baskets`, `fruits` and `basket_fruits` (join-table: `basket_id-fruit_id`).

How can I return a position of each fruit in basket so I will get something like

```
+---------------------------------------+
| basket_id | fruit_id | fruit_position |
|---------------------------------------|
| 1         | 2        | 1              |
| 1         | 5        | 2              |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Fruit position is just a number of a row in a returned joined table (it is not a column).

```
Schema:
baskets:       id, title
fruits:        id, title
basket_fruits: id, basket_id, fruit_id
```

Comment: Can you show the schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MySQL` does not support ranging functions so you'll have to use subqueries:

```
SELECT  basket_id, fruit_id,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    basket_fruit bfi
        WHERE   bfi.basket_id = bf.basket_id
                AND bfi.fruit_id <= bf.fruit_id
        ) AS fruit_position
FROM    basket_fruit bf
WHERE   basket_id = 1
```

or use session variables (faster but relies on implementation details which are not documented and may break in future releases):

```
SET @rn = 0;

SELECT  basket_id, fruit_id, @rn := @rn + 1 AS fruit_position
FROM    basket_fruit bf
WHERE   basket_id = 1
ORDER BY
        fruit_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any column in `basket_fruits` table that I would consider weightable. If you simply want to add some numbers to the data in that table, you could try this (this allows each basket to have its own *weights* counting from 1):

```
SET @current_group = NULL; 
SET @current_count = NULL;

SELECT 
id, basket_id, fruit_id,
CASE 
    WHEN @current_group  = basket_id THEN @current_count := @current_count + 1 
    WHEN @current_group := basket_id THEN @current_count := 1 
END AS fruit_position
FROM basket_fruits
ORDER BY basket_id, id
```

Sample input:

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | basket_id | fruit_id |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  2 |         2 |        5 |
|  6 |         2 |        1 |
|  9 |         1 |        2 |
| 15 |         2 |        3 |
| 17 |         1 |        5 |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Sample output:

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
| id | basket_id | fruit_id | fruit_position |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
|  9 |         1 |        2 |              1 |
| 17 |         1 |        5 |              2 |
|  2 |         2 |        5 |              1 |
|  6 |         2 |        1 |              2 |
| 15 |         2 |        3 |              3 |
+----+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: I was thinking about weights while I was writing title, but then I forget about it :) Thank you fro the answer. Going to try it

Answer (score 1):

SQL provides no guarantees on the order of the returned rows. Therefore `fruit_position` is likely to be different when queried from time to time. Most likely this will happen due to DML activity on your table.

If you really need some ordering, you should pick:

1. Use existing columns as ordering key, like fruit name (if exists)
2. Create a special field, like `seq_nr` that will specify ordering for your fruits.